# Oracle TO_CHAR Question - How to format number correctly?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a numberic field in an Oracle table of the format `NUMBER (7,4)`.  I'd like to display this in a query in the following format:

Value in table (e.g.):     17.5
Value to display:          17.5000

Value in table (e.g.):     3471.53
Value to display:          3471.5300

What Format Model do I need to apply to the `TO_CHAR` function that ensures that all the numbers to the left of the decimal space (however many there might be) are displayed and four decimal places are always displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mask for your format looks like:

```
select to_char(number_value, '999G999D0000') from dual;
```

Anyway, please get familiar with docs about format models.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm